# Android Apps: will receive "application not responding" after UIThread block more 5 seconds?

Tags: android, ui-thread

On Android Developer Site has said that :  We shouldn't use long operations work in `UIThread`. Instead, we should do it on another thread. At this site, they still say :

> if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5
>   seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous
>   "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.

To test this statement, I make a proof. Here is my code:

```
package com.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Example extends Activity{
    TextView  textView;
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("please wait");
        setContentView(textView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textView.setText("end waiting !!!");
    }

}
```

As you see, I make current thread (`UIThread`) sleep 8 seconds. So, I think, if I run this apps, Android will notice: "application not responding". But, I don't see any error. Program run smoothly (and I see text "end waiting", too).

So,who can explain for me about my code. What wrong thing I have made,please.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hqt in your sub-question (sorry  that I cannot post comment), If you want your program terminate, after you click your `button`, when your `button` in 8-seconds-running, you should click again your button, and the "magic" will happened as you wish :)

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that you don't generate any signal/event that gets blocked. Android displays that dialog when you or the system doesn't respond to an event within these 5 seconds. No event means no dialog.

So your code runs fine until you try to do something. If I run your code without doing anything, it works without issues. If I generate an event by pressing the menu-key at the start it will trigger an ANR because the key event could not be processed properly.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Good answer. If the OP intends to do anything that will block the UI Thread for more than 5 seconds it should go into an AsyncTask ideally.

Comment: @alextsc Can you give me a detailed example, please. I have create a new `button` and make it an event `onRefresh`. After that, when   I start apps, I press that `Button`, but still no problem happended. Here my code for refresh:

Comment: public void onRefresh(View view){
  try {
   Thread.sleep(8000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
  
  textView.setText("end waiting !!!");  
 }